# Select distinct if?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to SQL and I'd like to implement a query with a behavior that is quite difficult for me to write.

My 'user' table looks like this and is running under PostGRE

```
    id     |           email           | guest |           token            
-----------+---------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------
 6XH898SJ  | email@gmail.com           | t     | test_token_1234
 L7DJ456MV | another@gmail.com         | f     | faQ2UJFRKZNtieFGub6D0XwhfA1QqLD6lwU5DmIzBaI=
 L2CN592JV | tyesttest@gmail.com       | f     | gspCpQSOtuxNpT8n+C1szL12/YKvBfygfpGLPLoBDws=
 5KX442FK  | email@gmail.com           | f     | test_token_1234
```

It's simple :

Multiple guest user can exist with the same email.
Only one registered user can exist with a given email, but you can have a guest and a registered user holding at the same time.
The token is nothing more than a hash of the email, that's why it's the same for the first and the fourth user.

My request has to SELECT all the tokens for guest and non guest. But if two tokens are the same (ie the same email is used for two users) I need to retrieve the line WHERE guest is false.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: format your table

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, you can do this with `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (token) u.*
from user u
order by token, guest desc;
```